# 'GoDep' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, go, heroku, buildpack, godeps

I am trying to deploy my Go App on heroku, for which I am using Godep as build pack. After installing godep using the command

```
go get github.com/tools/godep
```

when I try to run

```
godep save
```

I am getting the error which states that 'godep' is not recognised as an internal or external command.

Below is my env variables.

[image]

Can someone please point out where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Fix your PATH env var.

Comment: @Volker : Setting GOBIN fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Setting the GOBIN value in the environment variables fixed the issue.

[image]

Comment: Most users should not set `GOBIN` to `GOROOT/bin`. Add the default `GOBIN` to your `PATH`

Comment: @JimB : Could you please provide the exact format of these environment variables as I am confused.

Comment: the default value for `GOBIN` is `$GOPATH/bin` -- you add that to your `PATH`.